# How to change behavior of \xordcode in encTeX

Tags: fonts

My setup: web2cTeX (TeX Live).
Consider xyz.tex:

```
\xordcode"27="0D
\tt '
\bye
```

and compile it with:

```
tex -ini -enc '\input plain \dump' # we need this for \xordcode to work
tex -fmt plain xyz.tex
```

I need to get ' here, but TeX produces empty result, because \xordcode makes TeX consider ' ("27) as ^M ("0D).

So, is there a way to change default \xordcode behavior so that it would only determine which character to take from corresponding font while actual typesetting, and not to try to influence other things?

Ideally, what I'm trying to acheive (in **PlainTeX**), is to produce \char"12 when I type ` (\char"60), and to produce \char"0D when I type ' (\char"27). If used with \tt, they will give proper ` and ', which I need, instead of default ‘ and ’.

Comment: `\` is U+0060 and has catcode 12 in plain, so \`  will typeset as `\char"60`  which is apparently what you want to happen.

Comment: @David  
echo cmtt10 | tex '\input testfont \table \end';  
xdvi testfont.dvi  - 
In positions '140 and '47 you have ‘ and ’, don't you?

Comment: Oh OK what I said is true but I see what you mean. Oh OK why use enctex for this rather than just `{\tt \catcode\`'\active \def'{\char"0D } .... 'foo'}`

Comment: @David Because I want ` and ' to keep their default properties. For example, for ' to work with constants (i.e., \char'39) it must have catcode 12, \char`\X must also work as before, etc.

Comment: Yes but that is much easier to control using active characters which can be local to a specific macro rather thna enctex which is global to a file

Comment: If not to use encTeX, currently I see only one solution to ` and ' quotes problem - to make my own font (exactly like cmtt, but with quotes in proper places - i.e. switch positions 18 <-> 96 and 13 <-> 39). But this is not portable. Besides, I will have also to make dvipdfmx aware of it, so that they will be copied and searched properly in pdf.

Comment: `\mubyte\mycommand '\endmubyte \def\mycommand{\char"0D}`
`\mubytein=1`
`\tt '`
`\bye`

I don't know whether the above is that you want or not.

Comment: @Akira No, because I want ` and ' to keep their default properties (see comment above). The problem is that instead of changing xord/xchr in TeX's "stomach", encTeX changes them in TeX's "mouth". And I'm asking how to change that behavior.

Comment: @Igor: What about
`\mubyte\mycommand '\endmubyte \def\mycommand{\char"0D} \mubytein=0`
`\let\oldtt\tt\def\tt{\mubytein=1\oldtt}`
`'{\tt '}'`
`\bye`

Comment: @Akira This will work for me, post this as the answer! This is similar to changing to active catcode (see above comment), but less cumbersome. (Although, the problem remains if one wishes to use non-english UTF-8 documents). Still, is there somebody who knows of a more general solution to manipulate font characters' positions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example by using encTeX:

```
\mubyte\myquoteout '\endmubyte\def\myquoteout{\char"0D}
\mubyte\myquotein `\endmubyte\def\myquotein{\char"12}\mubytein=0
\let\oldtt\tt\def\tt{\mubytein=1\oldtt}
%
`test' {\tt `test'} `test'
\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

TeX has no possibility to reencode during the expand processor state (this was my initial intent).

Two examples using active character:

```
\catcode`'\active\def'{\char"0D}\catcode`'=12
\catcode"60\active\def`{\char"12}\catcode"60=12
\let\oldtt\tt\def\tt{\catcode"60\active\catcode`'\active\oldtt}
%
`test' {\tt `test'} `test'
\bye
```

```
\def\adef#1{\catcode`#1=13 \begingroup \lccode`\~=`#1\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}}
\let\oldtt\tt\def\tt{\adef`{\char"12}\adef'{\char"0D}\oldtt}
%
`test' {\tt `test'} `test'
\bye
```

(adef macro is used in opmac.tex by Petr Olšák)